# Hubspot API not Working due to CORS

Tags: javascript, api, hubspot

I'm Using Hubspot API in AJAX Request. But showing Following error in **console**

So how to enable **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in Hubspot.

```
Failed to load https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/pages?hapikey=demo: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'https://preview.hs-sites.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If i can't enable **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in Hubspot, then what is next option to use this API.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The HubSpot API does not support cross origin CORS / AJAX requests, according to their support, by doing it client-side that'd expose the API key.

What you can do instead is to create a proxy server, where you'd make the requests from your own server and call the Hubspot endpoints, as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

const HUBSPOT_API_KEY = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
const HUBSPOT_ENDPOINT = `https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts?hapikey=${HUBSPOT_API_KEY}`

app.get('/api/hubspot', function(req, res) {
  request(HUBSPOT_ENDPOINT, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log('body:', body);
    res.json(body);
  });
});

app.listen(port);
```

Have in mind that it's just an example, to explain the idea to you, that uses nodejs/express/request and it's not meant for production! You can modify or use your favorite server language, platform etc to achieve the same.

You can use this principle to any endpoint that does not support cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

You can also allow set the Access to allow your URL 'https://preview.hs-sites.com' for the access on your server-
I had a similar issue while making post call to a service URL hosted on Azure, and this worked for me.